# Evaluate the following surface integral

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

$$\iint _D\left(z+5x-3y\right)d\sigma $$

where $D$ is the surface of the plane $10x+5y+4z=20$ located in the 1st octant

Need a quite a bit of help in solving this

Comment: Start with drawing it.

Comment: $10x+5y=20; 5y+4z=20; 10x+4z=20$

 Then $10x=20 => x=2 , 5y=20 => y= 4, 4z=20 => z=5$

So we gonna have $A(2,0,0) ; B(0,4,0); C(0,0,5) right? $

Comment: It's the right points of intersection with the axes.

Comment: Next step what is projection of this triangle on $OXY$?

Comment: Yep, I will update once I am done with it, I think I got it.